# Mysql install and remove issues

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I installed mysql on ubuntu server and i dont know what went wrong...it didnt install a mysql root user so i tried to uninstall and start over and now i cant unistall

i tried this

```
apt-get remove php5-mysql
apt-get remove mysql-server mysql-client
apt-get autoremove
```

but when i do

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

> ```
> root      6066  0.0  0.0   1772   540 pts/1    S    03:21   0:00 /bin/sh /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
> mysql     7065  0.0  0.6  58936 11900 pts/1    Sl   03:33   0:00 /usr/sbin/mysqld --   basedir=/usr --datadir=/var/lib/mysql --user=mysql --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid -- socket=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock --port=3306
> root      7066  0.0  0.0   2956   688 pts/1    S    03:33   0:00 logger -t mysqld -p daemon.error
> root     22804  0.0  0.0   3056   780 pts/1    R+   04:14   0:00 grep mysql
> ```

so i killed the processes and then tried to reinstall like this

```
apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
sudo mysqladmin -u root -h localhost password 'root'
```

but i get this

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
```

im confused..i keep installing and uninstalling mysql and the same result..any ideas

Comment: have you tried without password `mysql -u root -p` if it prompts for password just press enter

Comment: Why did you kill the processes???????

Comment: i tried it with it yes and still fail

Comment: ya i killed it because i was trying to delete everything

Comment: When you want to stop your car you run into the wall or just push the brake?

Comment: @zerkms I prefer to just run it into a wall. :)

Comment: @alex: it is definitely better than kill processes, rather that stop them.

Answer (score 0):

it's possible that mysql is using old config files from your previous installation.

the best way to remove a package is:

sudo dpkg --purge **package name**

This removes all obsolete config files as well!

Comment: i removed everything i could think of but i still get this  mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) so it seems still installed

Comment: it appears you're not supplying the password properly, thus the:

`(using password: NO)`

I believe, as someone also has mentioned, that the proper way to login is: 

`mysql -u root -p`

Answer (score 0):

The root password is stored in a special "mysql" database. Look in `/var/lib/mysql/mysql` and see if there is anything there.

In my case, I see:

```
# ls /var/lib/mysql/mysql
columns_priv.frm  help_category.frm  ndb_binlog_index.frm  slow_log.CSM               time_zone_transition.frm
columns_priv.MYD  help_category.MYD  ndb_binlog_index.MYD  slow_log.CSV               time_zone_transition.MYD
columns_priv.MYI  help_category.MYI  ndb_binlog_index.MYI  slow_log.frm               time_zone_transition.MYI
db.frm            help_keyword.frm   plugin.frm            tables_priv.frm            time_zone_transition_type.frm
db.MYD            help_keyword.MYD   plugin.MYD            tables_priv.MYD            time_zone_transition_type.MYD
db.MYI            help_keyword.MYI   plugin.MYI            tables_priv.MYI            time_zone_transition_type.MYI
event.frm         help_relation.frm  proc.frm              time_zone.frm              user.frm
event.MYD         help_relation.MYD  proc.MYD              time_zone_leap_second.frm  user_info.frm
event.MYI         help_relation.MYI  proc.MYI              time_zone_leap_second.MYD  user_info.MYD
func.frm          help_topic.frm     procs_priv.frm        time_zone_leap_second.MYI  user_info.MYI
func.MYD          help_topic.MYD     procs_priv.MYD        time_zone.MYD              user.MYD
func.MYI          help_topic.MYI     procs_priv.MYI        time_zone.MYI              user.MYI
general_log.CSM   host.frm           servers.frm           time_zone_name.frm
general_log.CSV   host.MYD           servers.MYD           time_zone_name.MYD
general_log.frm   host.MYI           servers.MYI           time_zone_name.MYI
```

If so, delete that directory and then reinstall.

You can also start mysql in a special no-password mode and then [reset the password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html).